# Maximum element and its position (row,column) of matrix

Tags: matrix

Can someone help me to get the maximum element of $m\times n$ matrix and corresponding row and column $(i,j)$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Max[mat]` and `Position[mat, Max[mat]]`.

Comment: I used `mat` variable as `MatrixForm`, so the `Position` function did not work, e.g., `Max /@ mat; Position[mat, Max /@ mat]`. Thanks @ Szabolcs.

Comment: @Frey See point 6. [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/12)

Comment: Yes, those tips help. I use `Table` form and it works well :)